# Error Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAuthIdentifierName()

Tags: laravel

I just create a model user.php on source app and when I reloaded the serve appear this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getAuthIdentifierName()

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check if user table contains primary key as 'id' and User model extends proper interfaces like Authenticatable.

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
```

Comment: Works! Just changing the default : class User extends Model {} , to: class User extends Authenticatable